Noetherian spaces with a generic point have the fixed point property
Let $X$ be a topological space.  Some definitions first:

$X$ is called Noetherian if it satisfies the descending chain condition on closed sets.  Equivalently, if all the subspaces of $X$ are compact.
A generic point of $X$ is a point $p\in X$ such that $\overline{\{p\}}=X$.
$X$ has the fixed point property if every continuous map $f:X\to X$ has a fixed point.  Note that a space with the fixed point property is necessarily $T_0$ (see for example here).


Theorem: Every Noetherian $T_0$ space with a generic point has the fixed point property.

I give a topological proof as an answer below.  It treats $X$ as a poset ordered by the specialization preorder ($x\le y$ meaning $x\in\overline{\{y\}}$), which is a partial order since $X$ is $T_0$.  Any continuous map $f:X\to X$ respects the order: $x\le y$ implies $f(x)\le f(y)$.
On the other hand, there are many theorems about order-preserving functions from a poset to itself having a fixed point (e.g., Knaster-Tarski, which does not apply here because the poset in this case is not a complete lattice; plus many others).
Question: Can the theorem above be shown as a consequence of some order-theory result about fixed points?

This is also a corollary of Edelman's fixed point theorem from On a fixed point theorem for partially ordered sets (although I don't think that citing that theorem is simpler than the proof below).

@Jakobian Thanks for the reference: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/0012365X7990013X. I took a looks and it's not clear to me how the result above is a corollary.  Would you be able to post an answer to explain?

I've posted an answer below, using slightly different theorem. As you say, I didn't look carefully enough before mentioning Edelman's result

Let me remark here that the result no longer holds if we relax Noetherian to compact (though pi-Base currently has no space known to be compact, $T_0$, with a generic point, but not satisfying the fixed point property). Indeed, an example would be the Alexandrov topology on $\omega + \omega^\ast$, which is clearly $T_0$, has a generic point (namely $0^\ast$), has a focal point (namely $0$ - and thus compact), but the map $n \mapsto n+1$, $n^\ast \mapsto (n+1)^\ast$ is continuous and has no fixed point.

This is to adress this part of the question:

Can the theorem above be shown as a consequence of some order-theory result about fixed points?

Consider the following theorem from A theorem on partially ordered sets, with applications to fixed point theorems by Abian and Brown,
Theorem 2. Let $P$ be a partially ordered set such that every non-empty well-ordered set $W\subseteq P$ has a supremum, $f:P\to P$ is monotone, there exists $p\in P$ with $p\leq f(p)$. Then $f$ has a fixed point.
A dual $(P, \leq)'$ of partial order $(P, \leq)$ is a partial order $(P, \leq')$ such that $x\leq' y$ iff $y\leq x$.
A dually well-ordered set is a partial order such that its dual is well-ordered.
Taking duals in theorem 2 we of course have:
Theorem 2'. Let $P$ be a partially ordered set such that every non-empty dually well-ordered set $W\subseteq P$ has an infimum, $f:P\to P$ is monotone, there exists $p\in P$ with $f(p)\leq p$. Then $f$ has a fixed point.
In their answer, PatrickR obtained that $P = (X, \leq)$ with specialization preorder is such that $P$ has a maximal element $p\in P$, that $f:P\to P$ is monotone for any continuous function $f$, and that there doesn't exist any sequence $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subseteq P$ such that $p_{n+1} < p_n$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$.
The last property implies that the only non-empty dually well-ordered subsets $W\subseteq P$ are the non-empty finite chains, and so they have a minimum. So we can apply theorem 2'.

I also found Höft & Höft Some fixed point theorems for partially ordered sets, who prove similar results.  In particular, in the last paragraph of section 1, "a poset with a largest element that satisfies the descending chain condition has the fixed point property".

Here is a topological proof of the result.
Denote the specialization preorder on $X$ by $x\le y$ if $x\in\overline{\{y\}}$.
It's a partial order since $X$ is $T_0$.
Let $f:X\to X$ be a continuous map.  So $x\le y$ implies $f(x)\le f(y)$.
Let $p$ be the (unique by $T_0$) generic point of $X$; that is, $p\ge x$ for all $x$.
In particular, $p\ge f(p)$.
Now repeatedly apply $f$ to both sides of this inequality.
Writing $p_0=p$ and $p_n=f(p_{n-1})$, $n=1,2,\dots$ for convenience,
one gets a sequence of points that is (not necessarily strictly) decreasing for the specialization order:
$$p\ge p_1\ge p_2\ge\cdots.$$
This corresponds to a (not necessarily strictly) decreasing sequence of closed sets
$$ \overline{\{p\}}\supseteq \overline{\{p_1\}}\supseteq \overline{\{p_2\}}\supseteq\cdots,$$
with each $p_n$ the unique generic point of $\overline{\{p_n\}}$.
By the Noetherian property, there must be some $n$ such that
$\overline{\{p_{n-1}\}}=\overline{\{p_n\}}$, and hence  $p_{n-1}=p_n$;
that is, $p_{n-1}$ is a fixed point of $f$.
